# Django Rest Framework ignore day, hour, minute, etc. for a DateField or DateTimeField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My app allows users to have one budget per day. I have everything (models, serializers, APIs) working with the `models.DateField` so that hours, minutes, etc. are ignored. Now I want to go even more coarse-grained and only allow one budget per month (i.e. ignore days). No need to worry about existing data.

I'm okay with either 1) ignoring the day value in any POST/GET/etc requests or 2) returning a 400 when POSTing to a day other than the first (e.g. `{'date':'2020-01-02', ...}` would fail when using the default ISO 8601 format)

How can I do this at the API, serializer, or Django model level? This requirement may change in the future, but I'm just looking for the easiest implementation for now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get exactly your issue, but as I understand:

1. Ignoring the day value:
   You can either post treat the data in your serializer by overriding create & update methods, or post save in your model, either by a signal or by overriding the save method to remove the day
2. Clean the data in the serializer to force date being like 2020-01-01:

> ```
> def validate_date(self, value):
>     if value.day != 1:
>         raise serializers.ValidationError("Date is invalid. It must be the first day of the month")
>     return value
> ```

[Serializer documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/)